# Retrieving a report stored on disk

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I have a report stored as an .cfm file.  I have been able to retrieve it fine with a cffile read. Now I want the option of retrieving only part of the report, say the first 50 lines. I decided to try a `fileReadLine()`:

```
<cfset repname = url['rep']>
<cfset type = url['type']>

<cfset dataFile = fileOpen("/var/www/reports/moxrep/#repname#.cfm", "read" ) >
<cfset i = 0>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop 
condition = "NOT FileIsEOF(dataFile) AND i LT 100">
<cfset i = i + 1>
<cfset inf = fileReadLine( dataFile ) > 
 #inf#
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
<cfset fileClose( dataFile ) >
```

It did not retrieve things at all correctly.  The formatting was messed up.  All the dynamic data in the report was missing.  The CSS links did not operate.  And there were many extra blank lines.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is fileReadLine just not meant for retrieving a formatted report?  And if not, is there any way to retrieve just part of the report with cffile?

Comment: What does the content of your report files look like?  Does it contain actual CFML code, hence the need to be a .cfm file?  Are you expecting the page to be executed by your ColdFusion server when you do a file read on it?

Comment: @duncan It contains HTML code for a table and a link to a CSS page. There was plenty of CFML code that generated it, but it does not reside in this file. It could be given an HTML extension. The text editor shows the data values embedded there. cffile read produces the correct report.  I didn't know what to expect with fileReadLine. I was trying to find out.

Comment: If your file is a typical HTML file it's likely that grabbing an arbitrary amount of lines from the file will result in invalid HTML, which might not render correctly in your browser.

Comment: this seems likely -- thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use cfhttp to get the report, then take that result and strip it down to what you need.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I've never used cfhttp, so will check your answer later if I get it working.

Comment: Well, I tried it, and it gave me back the report, but the CSS formatting was stripped out.  Do I need to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you realize that the FileOpen() function is actually reading the raw CFML template and not actually executing the queries that populate your report. Using the CFHTTP tag is definitely a better approach, but be careful because your rendered page is likely to contain all your CSS that would be necessary for the report to render properly so use View Source on your report to see if you want just 50 lines.

The question burning in my mind is "why" do you want just 50 lines? are you previewing the report? it is only 1 page long? Are you embedding it into a dashboard? You may want to consider modifying the  .cfm "report" so that the area you want to display elsewhere is wrapped with a specific tag (such as a Span or even something custom) and then when you fetch the report using CFHTTP, then you can parse the results with XMLParse() function (assuming it is properly formatted) and render the section of the report you actually want.

Comment: The users can create reports and may wish to retrieve or delete one that was previously created.  To be sure they are picking the right report they need a preview (it needn't be 50 lines specifically). No way to know in advance how long a report is, could be hundreds of pages, and I am uneasy about retrieving the whole thing if not needed.  I do mean to get back to trying CFHTTP, and like the suggestion of wrapping the preview in a given tag. Will get back to it after I clean up a bug elsewhere (can you imagine? I created a bug).

Comment: You are quite right, I don't know exactly what fileOpen does.  I am still learning the language, so when I need to do something I look for a feature that may be suitable.  Sometimes that works out well; sometimes the feature isn't what I expected.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: see my comment to Dale above

Comment: is the CSS included in the HTML file, or did you use a <link> tag?

Comment: yes I used <link rel -- the formatting that was hardcoded in worked fine.